# JQuery row clone and event attributes separation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script that clones tables rows and increment ids, names, and event attributes.

The problem I'm having is I would like to clone and increment the `onchange` event attribute inside the 1rs textfield (`id="code"`) and would like to clone/increment the `onkeyup` event attribute inside the second textfield (`id="qte"`)

Currently both onchange and onkeyup event are duplicated in both textfields.

Here is **Jquery**:

```
jQuery.fn.addClone = function() {

    return this.each(function() {

        // get row for cloningg
        var row = $(this).parents('tr');
        var parent = {};

        // use tbody or table parent
        if ( $(row).parents('tbody').length>0) {
            parent = $(row).parents('tbody');
        } else {
            parent = $(row).parents('table');
        }

        // inject clone
        var copy = $(row).clone();
        $(copy).addClass('sadey');
        $(copy).addClass('isclone');
        $(parent).append( copy );

        // remove last td and replace with remove html
        $('.sadey').children('td:last').remove();

        var id = ($('.isclone').length + 1);

        $('.sadey').append('<td><button class="btn btn-block btn-danger" id="clickme" onclick="$(this).killClone' + id +'()">Retirer</button></td>');

        // increment all ids and names
        $('.sadey').find('*').each(function() {
            var tempId = $(this).attr('id');
            if (typeof tempId != 'undefined' && tempId!='') {
                $(this).attr('id',tempId  + '_' +  id);
                $(this).attr('onchange','oncode_change' +  id + "(this.value)");
                $(this).attr('onkeyup','onqte_change' +  id + "(this.value)");
                //$(this).parents('div','txtHint3' +  id + "()");
            }
            var tempName = $(this).attr('name');
            if (typeof tempName != 'undefined' && tempName!='') {
                $(this).attr('name',tempName + '_' + id);
            }

        });

        // remove active tag
        $('.sadey').removeClass('sadey');

    });

};
```

And **HTML**:

```
<table class="table table-striped" id="FinancialDataTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="width: 10%;">Code</th>
            <th style="width: 5%;">Qté</th>
            <th style="width: 25%;">Produit</th>
            <th style="width: 25%;">Description</th>
            <th style="width: 25%;">Prix</th>
            <th style="width: 10%;">Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" id="code" name="code" class="form-control" onchange="oncode_change(this.value)"   />
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" name="qte" id="qte" class="form-control" value="1" onkeyup="onqte_change(this.value)" />
                </div>
            </td>
            <td colspan="3"><div id="txtHint3" style="width: 100%"> </div></td>
            <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" onClick="$(this).addClone();">Ajouter un autre article</button></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I also tried to update this part like this:

```
$('.sadey').find('*').each(function() {
    var tempId = $(this).attr('id');
    if (typeof tempId != 'undefined' && tempId!='') {
        $(this).attr('id',tempId  + '_' +  id);
        $("#code").attr('onchange','oncode_change' +  id + "(this.value)");
        $("#qte").attr('onkeyup','onqte_change' +  id + "(this.value)");
        //$(this).parents('div','txtHint3' +  id + "()");
    }
    var tempName = $(this).attr('name');
    if (typeof tempName != 'undefined' && tempName!='') {
        $(this).attr('name',tempName + '_' + id);
    }
```

This solutions actually works but when I run it the order of the input field (1,2,3,4,5,etc) is messed up and the DIV is not cloning/incrementing no more which might be cause by some logic problem..

I am very new to JQuery and any help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: why do you want to duplicate the events.....

Comment: because the onchange event will call the function oncode_change() and the onkeyup will call another function onqte_change() both will be reassembled to send some data to an external PHP file

Comment: So I need the `onchange="oncode_change(this.value)"` inside the texfield with ID "code" and I need the `onkeyup="onqte_change(this.value)"` inside the other input with ID "qte". Both must be incrementing(which they already do) but separated and calling 2 different functions

Comment: ***I do not want to duplicate the events. I want each event in their input field. (Currently the problem is the events are duplicating)